# Show\Hide Text Field with Table View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to find some sample code or some guidance on how to show\hide text fields at the top of a table view. I've attached an example of what i'm looking to do. Do I just need to have a view controller and add text fields and a table view to it, or can I use a table view controller? Any guidance is very appreciated. [image]

Comment: If you are implementing a search, look into `UISearchBar` and `UISearchController` - they might save you reinventing a wheel.  Apple Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/)

Comment: One way but not the only way is to create. UIViewController and add  a UISearchController and a TableView. The other way is to use UITablewViewController and add a UISearchbar in the header view.

Comment: I looked into using a UISearchBar, but can't find a way to have 2 text fields. No issues with 1. I'm afraid i'm going to have to make myself.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use two UISearchBars above your UITableView. You can create as many as you need, you're not limited to one per view controller

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new View Controller, and just adding two text fields and a table view. I never could make it all work correctly with any other solution.